# How to remove default padding in android device

Tags: flutter, mobile

Here's the git repo `https://github.com/ianvillamia/elements/blob/master/lib/Screens/Authentication/landing.dart`

[image: What I wanted to achieve]

[image: What I did lol]

What I've done: 
Set the width of the container to its max size using this 
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width but it still has some padding/spaces
How do I remove this? padding. THANKS!

Comment: Can we get some code to help you more please ?

Comment: oops my bad https://github.com/ianvillamia/elements/blob/master/lib/Screens/Authentication/landing.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 15 of your code, you have a `Padding` widget that wrap your `Column` widget. So, all the children of the column have a padding.

**Solution 1**

Delete your padding widget

**Solution 2**

Keep your padding widget but don't add horizontal padding and only have vertical padding.

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmmetric(vertical: 15.0),
  child: Column()
)
```